# Using long IF value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to write a very simple IF statement with one very long value.

```
=IF(C2=1, "Please review the format of the plan; it needs to be cleaned up. Each learning outcome should be entered as a separate row. Each outcome can have multiple measures. Without this, it is difficult to demonstrate which outcomes align with which measure, benchmarks, findings, and changes. Please correct this as soon as possible, for the 2018-19 plan, so that a reviewer could potentially look in the system to decipher how these items align. The system is now open for such changes. This formatting issue likely made a fair evaluation of the 2017-18 assessment plan/report challenging, and would be equally challenging for an external reviewer to understand.", )
```

The error message is

> "Text values in formulas are limited to 255 characters. To create longer text values in a formula, use the CONCATENATE function or the concatenation operator (&)."

I understand the concept, I just don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Your message has more than 600 characters. So you are getting the error. The error message provides the solution to use the Concatenate function or & to circumvent the limitation of 255 characters.

Divide your message with Concatenate.

```
Concatenate(text1,[text2],[text3],...)
```

Your formula will be like:

```
=IF(C2=1,CONCATENATE("Please review the format of the plan; it needs to be cleaned up."," Each learning outcome should be entered as a separate row."," Each outcome can have multiple measures. Without this, it is difficult to demonstrate which outcomes align with which measure, benchmarks, findings, and changes."," Please correct this as soon as possible, for the 2018-19 plan,"," so that a reviewer could potentially look in the system to decipher how these items align. The system is now open for such changes."," This formatting issue likely made a fair evaluation of the 2017-18 assessment plan/report challenging, and would ","be equally challenging for an external reviewer to understand"),)
```

Comment: Excellent (and it works!) Thanks very much/jj

Comment: Good :) Then, you should mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(C2=1,=Z1&Z2&Z3)`
mashes together the contents of cell Z1, Z2, and Z3. There is no limit to the number of cells to bring together when using the ampersand "&", and there is no need to put a space between cells or values (although you can separate cell contents with
`=IF(C2=1,=Z1&" "&Z2&" "&Z3)`.

`=IF(C2=1,CONCATENATE(cell1, " " ,cell2, " " ,cell 3, " " ... " " ,cell255))`
can be used in lieu of the expression with the ampersand "&" above, but is limited to bringing together the contents of only 255 cells, and needs a space between each element.

Different versions of Excel have different limits of the number of characters per cell; 255 is common. Since your phrase is 656 characters long, you will probably need three (3) cells to hold all the text to concatenate.

To make it easy to know where to split that phrase into three parts, Microsoft Word has a way to count characters.  Put that long phrase in an otherwise empty Word document and click in the status bar at the bottom on the "Word Count"  metric. A Word Count dialog pops up, and shows the file summary that includes number of pages, words, characters (with and without spaces), paragraphs and lines in that file.

Comment: Good :) Then, you should mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the grey up arrowhead and the checkmark.